# How to verify if class implements a rich comparison method?

Tags: python, new-style-class

With the old style classes simply using `hasattr` works:

```
>>> class old:
...     pass
...
>>> hasattr(old, '__eq__')
False
```

Using the new style classes every class has the attribute `__eq__`:

```
>>> class nsc(object):
...     pass
...
>>> hasattr(nsc, '__eq__')
True
```

This is the expected behaviour as `hasattr(object, '__eq__')` also returns `True`. This is true for every rich comparison method.

How to verify if class implements a rich comparison method if I can't use `hasattr`? One thing that comes to mind is to call the method and see if it raises a `NotImplemented` exception. But calling those methods may have unexpected damages.

Comment: *"calling those methods may have unexpected damages"* - like what? What is your objective here?

Comment: I'm using this in a decorator function so I have no clue on what the user will be doing on such methods. I don't think calling them will be a good idea.

Comment: But what does the decorator *do*? What kind of classes is it decorating? Does it need to check this when it's applied? It would be very unusual for a comparison method to change the state of its parameters.

Comment: Right now it's a decorator that verifies if the class implements a minimum set of reach comparisons, it will become something else in the future.  I agree that is unusual for a comparison method to change the state of its parameters but I don't have control over it.

Comment: Have a look at how `functools.total_ordering` does it; you can check whether they're implemented directly or inherited from `object` pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you that's pretty cool. But how would I check if they were implemented directly or inherited from object?

Comment: ...in the same way that decorator does it!

Comment: Haha I'll take a look at it

Comment: They just use `dir` thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `dir` instead of `hasattr`. Rich comparison methods don't appear in the list returned by the `dir` function.

```
>>> class nsc(object):
...     pass
...
>>> '__eq__' in dir(nsc)
False
```